# Display multiple markers with Google maps API v3

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps

I can't display more than 10 markers on my Google Map. My coordinates was stock in csv file and below 10 markers, all markers was display in my map.
Does the API use restriction?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think so... If you play with the [sample code][1], you can place more than 10 markers... There must be something wrong in your code. But we can say unless you share the code :) [1]https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code : I must add about 50 markers

```
csTextMarkers.Append("var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();");
csTextMarkers.Append("var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(");
csTextMarkers.AppendFormat("{0}, {1}", geo.Latitude.Replace(',', '.'), geo.Longitude.Replace(',', '.'));
csTextMarkers.Append("), map: map, ");
//Filtre "N/D"
if (geo.Dimension_Ent == "null")
{
    csTextMarkers.Append("icon: 'http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%7c9E7151%7c000000&.png%3f', ");
}
//Filtre "< 500 K"
else if (geo.Dimension_Ent == "500 K")
{
    csTextMarkers.Append("icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/purple-dot.png' ");
}
csTextMarkers.Append("});");
csTextMarkers.Append("google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {infowindow.setContent(\"" + "Nom : " + geo.Nom + "<br/> Adresse : " + geo.Adresse1 + " " + geo.Code_Postal + " " + geo.Ville + "<br/> Dimension entreprise : " + geo.Dimension_Ent + "\"); infowindow.open(map,this);});");
```